# Remove Element If There is Certain Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to remove #tagfilter element when there is an h1 on the same page that contains "NEW ARRIVALS."

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr03uet2/

HTML:

```
<div class="inner">
    <h1 class="pagetitle row">NEW ARRIVALS</h1>
    <div class="close-row">
      <div class="navdrop" id="tagfilter" name="tagfilter">
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals">All</oa>
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/bras">Bras</oa>
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/crossbody">Crossbody</a>
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/jeans">Jeans</a>
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/pants">Pants</a> 
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/pullovers">Pullovers</a>    
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/satchels">Satchels</a>   
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/shirts">Shirts</a>
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/tops">Tops</a>
        <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/totes">Totes</a>
      <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQUery:

```
$(function () {
if ($("h1").contains("NEW ARRIVALS")) {
$("#tagfilter").remove();
}
});
```

Comment: where did the contains method come from? (it's a selector filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr03uet2/5/)

This will do it:

```
$(function () {
    if( $("h1:contains('NEW ARRIVALS')").length ) {
        $("#tagfilter").remove();
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$(function () {
    $("h1:contains('NEW ARRIVALS')").length === 0 || $("#tagfilter").remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr03uet2/6/)

Comment: why is .length necessary?

Comment: @JaeeunLee `.length` tells you if found or not. In other words, the `$()` he's using is to create a jQuery object based on the selector inside. If something of that nataure is found, then it will have a length of 1 or more. If nothing is found it will be 0

Comment: Without .length the expression would always evaluate to a *truthy*

Comment: The second one seems to work better in my context for some reason. The first one removed #tagfilter whenever there was NEW ARRIVALS on the page, even in a different tag. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting! Got a demo?

Comment: @PeterKA Actually the first one works too. I don't know why that happened when I tried it earlier.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(":contains(NEW ARRIVALS)").is("h1") && $("#tagfilter").remove();
```

```js
  $(function () {
      $(":contains(NEW ARRIVALS)").is("h1") &&  $("#tagfilter").remove();
      console.log($("#tagfilter").is("*"))
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="pagetitle row">NEW ARRIVALS</h1>
        <div class="close-row">
          <div class="navdrop" id="tagfilter" name="tagfilter">
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals">All</oa>
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/bras">Bras</oa>
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/crossbody">Crossbody</a>
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/jeans">Jeans</a>
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/pants">Pants</a> 
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/pullovers">Pullovers</a>    
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/satchels">Satchels</a>   
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/shirts">Shirts</a>
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/tops">Tops</a>
            <a href="http://www.achengshop.com/collections/newarrivals/totes">Totes</a>
          <div>
        </div>
    </div>
```